# Why can't selenium parse the site and throws an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-parsing

I wrote the parsing code in bs4, but then I had to remake it for selenium. When you run the code, chrome-driver opens, but then closes and displays nothing but an error. At the beginning of parsing, chrome-driver opens and many words "word word word word ..." are displayed and at the end only a link is displayed in the console

```
# aiogram
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types.message import ParseMode
from bot import dp
from bot import db
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold, hlink
import cfscrape

import fake_headers

# python
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# default для mvc
city = "belgorod"
city2 = "voronezh"
city3 = "kursk"

radius = 300
allowed_data = ['часов', 'часа','час']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

stealth(
        driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
)

  @dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Воронеж")
    async def avito_list(message: types.Message):
        try:
            # Проверим есть ли вообще подписки
            if db.follows_exists(message.from_user.id):
    
                # Выводим все объявления по подпискам
                follows = db.show_subs(message.from_user.id)
    
                for follow in follows:
                    line = follow[1][0][0]
    
                    with db.connection:
                        marka = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT `avito_mark_name` FROM `marks` WHERE `name` = ?", (line,)).fetchall()
                        marka = marka[0][0]
    
                    min_price = follow[2][0][0]
                    if follow[3][0][0] == None:
                        max_price = follow[2][0][0]*1000
                    else:
                        max_price = follow[3][0][0]
                    #model = "2114_samara"
                    #url = f"https://www.avito.ru/{city}/avtomobili/{marka}/{model}?radius={radius}"
                    url = f"https://www.avito.ru/valuyki/avtomobili/{marka}-ASgBAgICAUTgtg3GmSg?cd=1&radius=200"
                    driver.get(url)
                    time.sleep(5)
                    print(url)
    
                    main_container = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,".iva-item-content")
    
                    for index, content in enumerate(main_container):
                        contaier_of_content = content.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".iva-item-body")
    
    
    
                        ad_post = contaier_of_content.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "item-line")
    
    
                        #fresh_car = contaier_of_content.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,{"data-marker":"item-date"}).text.split()[1]
                        price = content.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".price-price").find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "price").get_attribute("content")
    
                        if int(price) <= max_price and int(price) >= min_price: # проверка на сегодняшний день и на подхождение по цене
    
    
    
                            title_info = contaier_of_content.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'.iva-item-title').get_attribute("title").split(',')
                            town_info = contaier_of_content.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'.geo-root').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"span").text
                            datePost_info = contaier_of_content.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,'.iva-item-dateInfo').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,"div").text
                            #link = content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-sliderLink*'))['href']
    
                            currency = content.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.price-price').find_element(By.TAG_NAME,'meta').get_attribute("content")
                            car_info = title_info[0]
                            was_created = title_info[1]
                            city_on_sale = town_info
    
                            card = f'{hlink(car_info+" - "+was_created,"https://avito.ru"+link)}\n' \
                                f'{hbold("Город: ", city_on_sale)}\n' \
                                f'{hbold("Цена: ", price, currency)}'
    
    
    
                            await message.answer(card)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
        finally:
            driver.close()
            driver.quit()
```

this is displayed in the console

https://www.avito.ru/valuyki/avtomobili/volkswagen-ASgBAgICAUTgtg3GmSg?cd=1&radius=200

https://www.avito.ru/valuyki/avtomobili/vaz_lada-ASgBAgICAUTgtg3GmSg?cd=1&radius=200

Comment: What is your intent with this line: iva-item-content*

Comment: @iohans want to parse card data on the website

Comment: @iohans can i send you the same code for bs4? I really need to convert it to selenium

Comment: Are you expecting main_container to be a list of all IDs or classes (that contain iva-item-content)? Yeah, you can provide the bs4 code.

Comment: @iohans updated the question and changed everything there to bs4

Comment: @iohans I'm waiting for your answer:)

Comment: Can you put back your attempt in Selenium? I am not sure how much more I can help, but I will try. The selectors are mostly the issues that I run into. And, I did notice a few typos in the code (i.e., contaier_of_content).

Comment: @iohans Yes, I'll return it now

Comment: @iohans returned to selenium. I hope for your help, I just need it to work the same as on bs4

Comment: I mean, please include your bs4 code AND your attempt. This will help me and others debug.

Comment: @iohans I included the code on bs4 and everything is perfectly parsed

Comment: @iohans I just need to rewrite the code written in bs4 to selenium

Comment: Can you post the URL, full code, and re-format it with proper indentation?

Comment: @AbiSaran updated for you and posted full code, hope you can help

Answer (score 0):

**I was able to solve the problem by combining the work of bs4 and selenium, thanks to this the parser started working**

```
# aiogram
from aiogram import types
from aiogram.types.message import ParseMode
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from bot import dp
from bot import db
from aiogram.utils.markdown import hbold, hlink
import cfscrape

import fake_headers

# python
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium_stealth import stealth
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# default для mvc
city = "belgorod"
city2 = "voronezh"
city3 = "kursk"

radius = 300
allowed_data = ['часов', 'часа','час']

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

stealth(
        driver,
        languages=["en-US", "en"],
        vendor="Google Inc.",
        platform="Win32",
        webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
        renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
        fix_hairline=True,
)


#def get_session(url):
    #session = requests.Session()
    #session.headers = {
    #    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
    #    'Accept-Language':'ru,en-US;q=0.5',
   # }
    #return cfscrape.create_scraper(sess=session)

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Белгород")
async def avito_list(message: types.Message):
    try:
        # Проверим есть ли вообще подписки
        if db.follows_exists(message.from_user.id):

            # Выводим все объявления по подпискам
            follows = db.show_subs(message.from_user.id)

            for follow in follows:
                line = follow[1][0][0]

                with db.connection:
                    marka = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT `avito_mark_name` FROM `marks` WHERE `name` = ?", (line,)).fetchall()
                    marka = marka[0][0]

                min_price = follow[2][0][0]
                if follow[3][0][0] == None:
                    max_price = follow[2][0][0]*1000
                else:
                    max_price = follow[3][0][0]
                #model = "2114_samara"
                #url = f"https://www.avito.ru/{city}/avtomobili/{marka}/{model}?radius={radius}"
                url = f"your url"
                driver.get(url)
                source_data = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source_data, 'lxml')


                time.sleep(5)
                print('Начинаю собирать информацию')

                main_container = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-content*'))

                for index, content in enumerate(main_container):
                    contaier_of_content = content.find("div", class_=re.compile("iva-item-body*"))

                    ad_post = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-line"})

                    fresh_car = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-date"}).text.split()[1]
                    price = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta', itemprop="price")[
                        'content']

                    if int(price) <= max_price and int(
                            price) >= min_price:  # проверка на сегодняшний день и на подхождение по цене

                        title_info = contaier_of_content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-title*'))['title'].split(
                            ',')
                        town_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('geo-root*')).find('span').text
                        datePost_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-dateInfo*')).find(
                            'div').text
                        link = content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-sliderLink*'))['href']

                        currency = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta')['content']
                        car_info = title_info[0]
                        was_created = title_info[1]
                        city_on_sale = town_info

                        card = f'{hlink(car_info + " - " + was_created, "https://avito.ru" + link)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Город: ", city_on_sale)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Цена: ", price, currency)}'

                        await message.answer(card)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        print('Миссия выполнена, сэр!')

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Воронеж")
async def avito_list(message: types.Message):
    try:
        # Проверим есть ли вообще подписки
        if db.follows_exists(message.from_user.id):

            # Выводим все объявления по подпискам
            follows = db.show_subs(message.from_user.id)

            for follow in follows:
                line = follow[1][0][0]

                with db.connection:
                    marka = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT `avito_mark_name` FROM `marks` WHERE `name` = ?", (line,)).fetchall()
                    marka = marka[0][0]

                min_price = follow[2][0][0]
                if follow[3][0][0] == None:
                    max_price = follow[2][0][0]*1000
                else:
                    max_price = follow[3][0][0]
                #model = "2114_samara"
                #url = f"https://www.avito.ru/{city}/avtomobili/{marka}/{model}?radius={radius}"
                url = f"your url"
                driver.get(url)
                source_data = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source_data, 'lxml')


                time.sleep(5)
                print('Начинаю собирать информацию')

                main_container = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-content*'))

                for index, content in enumerate(main_container):
                    contaier_of_content = content.find("div", class_=re.compile("iva-item-body*"))

                    ad_post = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-line"})

                    fresh_car = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-date"}).text.split()[1]
                    price = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta', itemprop="price")[
                        'content']

                    if int(price) <= max_price and int(
                            price) >= min_price:  # проверка на сегодняшний день и на подхождение по цене

                        title_info = contaier_of_content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-title*'))['title'].split(
                            ',')
                        town_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('geo-root*')).find('span').text
                        datePost_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-dateInfo*')).find(
                            'div').text
                        link = content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-sliderLink*'))['href']

                        currency = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta')['content']
                        car_info = title_info[0]
                        was_created = title_info[1]
                        city_on_sale = town_info

                        card = f'{hlink(car_info + " - " + was_created, "https://avito.ru" + link)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Город: ", city_on_sale)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Цена: ", price, currency)}'

                        await message.answer(card)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        print('Миссия выполнена, сэр!')

@dp.message_handler(lambda message: message.text == "Курск")
async def avito_list(message: types.Message):
    try:
        # Проверим есть ли вообще подписки
        if db.follows_exists(message.from_user.id):

            # Выводим все объявления по подпискам
            follows = db.show_subs(message.from_user.id)

            for follow in follows:
                line = follow[1][0][0]

                with db.connection:
                    marka = db.cursor.execute(f"SELECT `avito_mark_name` FROM `marks` WHERE `name` = ?", (line,)).fetchall()
                    marka = marka[0][0]

                min_price = follow[2][0][0]
                if follow[3][0][0] == None:
                    max_price = follow[2][0][0]*1000
                else:
                    max_price = follow[3][0][0]
                #model = "2114_samara"
                #url = f"https://www.avito.ru/{city}/avtomobili/{marka}/{model}?radius={radius}"
                url = f"your url"
                driver.get(url)
                source_data = driver.page_source
                soup = BeautifulSoup(source_data, 'lxml')


                time.sleep(5)
                print('Начинаю собирать информацию')

                main_container = soup.find_all('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-content*'))

                for index, content in enumerate(main_container):
                    contaier_of_content = content.find("div", class_=re.compile("iva-item-body*"))

                    ad_post = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-line"})

                    fresh_car = contaier_of_content.find("div", {"data-marker": "item-date"}).text.split()[1]
                    price = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta', itemprop="price")[
                        'content']

                    if int(price) <= max_price and int(
                            price) >= min_price:  # проверка на сегодняшний день и на подхождение по цене

                        title_info = contaier_of_content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-title*'))['title'].split(
                            ',')
                        town_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('geo-root*')).find('span').text
                        datePost_info = contaier_of_content.find('div', class_=re.compile('iva-item-dateInfo*')).find(
                            'div').text
                        link = content.find('a', class_=re.compile('iva-item-sliderLink*'))['href']

                        currency = content.find('span', class_=re.compile('price-price-*')).find('meta')['content']
                        car_info = title_info[0]
                        was_created = title_info[1]
                        city_on_sale = town_info

                        card = f'{hlink(car_info + " - " + was_created, "https://avito.ru" + link)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Город: ", city_on_sale)}\n' \
                               f'{hbold("Цена: ", price, currency)}'

                        await message.answer(card)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    finally:
        print('Миссия выполнена, сэр!')
```